# How can I detect when the midpoint of a UICollectionViewCell is outside the frame of the UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I know that the `UITableViewDataSource` method below will notify me when the entire cell has been hidden.

`func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {}`

But I need a method that will notify me when **half of the cell** is hidden.

In other words, I need a method that will be triggered when the cell has been scrolled to the point that half of the cell is visible and half of it is not.

Comment: Could you elaborate on half the cell being hidden?

Comment: I need a trigger for when the cell has been scrolled to the point that half of it is visible and half of it is not.

Comment: Does it necessarily have to be a delegate call somewhere? If not. A possible solution is to check the bounds of the cell manually by first converting the cell's bounds to your view's space. And then, you can check for the middle coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really an easy way to go about it. But this should do the trick. What you want to do is detect when the collectionView scrolls then determine which cells are fully visible and which cells have their center "off screen". If a cell was recently fully visible, but the center is no longer on screen, we can assume that that cell is roughly 50% visible.

For this to work you need to keep track of which cells were recently fully visible, then as a cell's center moves off screen remove the cell from the list. If you don't remove the cell from the list then it would be processed repeatedly since its center will be off screen on more than one iteration of scroll detection.

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    // ...

    var recentlyFullyVisibleCells: Set<IndexPath> = .init()

    func processOffScreenCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { return }
        cell.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    func processFullyVisibleCell(at indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) else { return }
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let latestFullyVisibleCells = collectionView.visibleCells.filter { cell in
            // Get cells that are fully visible
            let rect = collectionView.convert(cell.frame, to: collectionView.superview)
            return collectionView.frame.contains(rect)
        }
        .compactMap { cell in
            // Convert to IndexPath
            collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        }

        latestFullyVisibleCells.forEach { indexPath in
            processFullyVisibleCell(at: indexPath)
        }

        collectionView.visibleCells.filter { cell in
            // Get cells whose center are not on screen
            let rect = collectionView.convert(cell.frame, to: collectionView.superview)
            return !collectionView.frame.contains(CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.midY))
        }
        .compactMap { cell in
            // Convert to IndexPath
            collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
        }
        .reduce(into: Set<IndexPath>()) { result, indexPath in
            // Convert to Set
            result.insert(indexPath)
        }
        .intersection(recentlyFullyVisibleCells) // Only keep cells that were recently fully visible
        .forEach { indexPath in
            processOffScreenCell(at: indexPath)
            recentlyFullyVisibleCells.remove(indexPath)
        }

        recentlyFullyVisibleCells.formUnion(latestFullyVisibleCells)
    }

    override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        recentlyFullyVisibleCells.removeAll()
    }

    // ...

}
```